# Is it possible to change the default record type using Visual force page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, record-type

when i save the data ,it saved as the default record type?,Is it possible to change it?

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags to your questions - this is not related to Salesforce1, DX, or Communities.

Comment: You'll need a Visualforce controller for the page.  If you don't know how to write a VF controller, you can learn on the Salesforce Trailhead site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.You can do that

You want to save the record to specific record type, provide the "recordtypeid" of that record while saving the record.

Please check in profile level,you have to enabled the "record types"

you can obtain a Record Type in code in the following way:

```
Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.OBJECT_NAME.getRecordTypeInfosByName()
              .get('RECORD_TYPE_NAME').getRecordTypeId();
```

//RECORD_TYPE_NAME->Provide the record type name

You have to use that record type id while saving record

```
              Account acc = new Account(Name='Test1', RecordTypeId = recordTypeId);
```